# GitHub: Sorry, this diff is unavailable (fork removed)

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I try to merge [this pull request](https://github.com/304NotModified/Fody.Stamp/pull/22) but the fork is already removed.

[image]

The pull requests still shows the correct changes, but I'm unable to get/merge the changes (I'm aware of the conflicts, that's not the problem).

Github shows in the bottom of the PR the command lines:

[image]

but the `curl -L https://github.com/304NotModified/Fody.Stamp/pull/22.patch | git am -3` won't work.

I found out that https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/304NotModified/Fody.Stamp/pull/22.diff
is showing the error: "Sorry, this diff is unavailable"

[image]

Any idea how to get the changes (locally)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, GitHub won't show you the diff like this any more.

Fortunately, the original commits *are* still attached to the upstream repository:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/304NotModified/Fody.Stamp
Cloning into 'Fody.Stamp'...
remote: Counting objects: 1102, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 1102 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1100
Receiving objects: 100% (1102/1102), 2.07 MiB | 3.10 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (718/718), done.
$ cd Fody.Stamp
```

This next part is the real trick:

```
$ git fetch origin refs/pull/22/head:refs/heads/pr22
remote: Counting objects: 42, done.
remote: Total 42 (delta 27), reused 27 (delta 27), pack-reused 15
Unpacking objects: 100% (42/42), done.
From git://github.com/304NotModified/Fody.Stamp
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/22/head -> pr22
```

As long as you have command-line Git, you can work this way.  It's *better*, too, as you have the original commits, and hence can use `git cherry-pick` on them one at a time, or `git merge` (with or without `--squash`) to merge them, or `git rebase` to copy them, or whatever.

```
$ git log --decorate --oneline --graph master pr22
*   950ecea (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Merge pull request #47 from 304NotModified/fix-unstable-test
|\  
| * fb12f67 fix unstable test
* |   401e787 (tag: 1.4.2) Merge pull request #45 from 304NotModified/fix-dependency

[mass snippage]

* 3e6ddf0 Update README.md
*   73e9e51 Merge pull request #25 from 304NotModified/patch-1
|\  
| * c1cad0b Syntax highlighting
* | 0e3dac1 (tag: 1.3.1) mark as  (no longer maintained)
* | 18f6705 Update README.md
* | 1382fa8 (tag: 1.3.0) update cecil
|/  
| * ac637e3 (pr22) Update README
| * 0f51ff7 Add tests for UseFileVersion and OverwriteFileVersion
| * 5d2517f Refactor and fix tests
| * 449db14 Add OverwriteFileVersion in config (default true)
| * 8be5aa1 Use AssemblyFileVersion to format AssemblyInformationalVersion if UseFileVersion is true
| * 26c6fdd Add Configuration.UseAssemblyFileVersion
| * 58635c2 Refactor a little
| * 4bf8d6a Add more tokens to README
|/  
* 5e64e14 bump refs
```

Comment: `git fetch origin refs/pull/22/head:refs/heads/pr22` was exactly what I needed! Thx!